# Is there a way to export Blockly Turtle graphics to SVG?

Tags: blockly

My children are having fun with Blockly, and I'd like to mill some of their drawings with my Shapeoko (a CNC mill).  If I could export the Blockly rendering as SVG, I could then import it into any number of CAD/CAM packages.

But there doesn't seem to be any easy way to do this.  The current routes I'm considering are:

1. Grabbing a screenshot of the image and converting it from raster image to SVG with Inkscape.
2. Converting the Blockly code to use Python's turtle module.

Am I missing anything?  There should be a better way.

Comment: I don't think enough people use Blockly for you to get an answer. :-/

Comment: I'd like to think that blocksvg would hold the answer for this --- I wish there was a nice 2D drawing tool implemented in Blockly as a corollary to Blockscad3D --- might be that you could use the 2D objects from that?

Comment: Doesn't it depend on the blockly output? Are you drawing on a canvas or...?